# Do I need to apply separate visa if my destination is France and my flight transit via Germany?

Tags: visas, schengen, transit-visas, schengen-visas

I am travelling to France from Singapore next month (I am not a Singapore National and my nationality requires visa to enter France). My flight itinerary is **Singapore -> Frankfurt, Germany -> France** I am currently in the process of applying France Schengen visa. Do i need another visa from Germany for my transit?

Answer (score 0):

No, the France visa allows you to do that.